# Xapian gem failed to install on Mac OS X Snow Leopard + macports

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, macports, xapian

I have installed xapian-core + xapian-bindings with macports on snow leopard, then trying to install xapian gem fails:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing xapian:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/ruby extconf.rb
./configure --with-ruby
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.3.0
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin10.3.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking for xapian-config... /opt/local/bin/xapian-config
checking /opt/local/bin/xapian-config works... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for ruby1.8... no
checking for ruby... /opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/ruby
checking /opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/ruby version... ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.2.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2009.10
checking for /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.2.0/ruby.h... yes
checking ruby/io.h... no
checking whether to use -fvisibility=hidden... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating xapian-version.h
config.status: creating python/Makefile
config.status: creating python/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating php/Makefile
config.status: creating php/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating java/Makefile
config.status: creating java/native/Makefile
config.status: creating java/org/xapian/Makefile
config.status: creating java/org/xapian/errors/Makefile
config.status: creating java/org/xapian/examples/Makefile
config.status: creating java-swig/Makefile
config.status: creating tcl8/Makefile
config.status: creating tcl8/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating tcl8/pkgIndex.tcl
config.status: creating csharp/Makefile
config.status: creating csharp/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating csharp/AssemblyInfo.cs
config.status: creating ruby/Makefile
config.status: creating ruby/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating xapian-bindings.spec
config.status: creating python/generate-python-exceptions
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands

*** Building bindings for languages: ruby

make
make  all-recursive
Making all in ruby
make  all-recursive
Making all in docs
make  all-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.2.0 -I/opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.2.0  -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -fvisibility=hidden -I/opt/local/include -g -O2 -MT xapian_wrap.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/xapian_wrap.Tpo -c -o xapian_wrap.lo xapian_wrap.cc
../libtool: line 393: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 393: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 792: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
: ignoring unknown tag 
../libtool: line 792: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
*** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.
*** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1103: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1156: /bin/sed: No such file or directory
: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `'
make[4]: *** [xapian_wrap.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
extconf.rb:3:in `system!': unhandled exception
    from extconf.rb:6


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-1.0.15 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-1.0.15/gem_make.out
```

Any idea pal?

Answer (score 2):

symlink sed into the /bin dir